# Fetch Google Group members

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-groups

I'm trying to fetch all the members of a Google Group using the discovery API.
So I used the code given in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/query-memberships#searching_for_all_memberships_in_a_group) but I get the following error:

```
'Error(2033): Group resource name has the correct format of `groups/{group_id}`, but it contains an invalid `{groupd_id}`
```

I used as `group_id` the email of the Google Group or the plain text name but the error persists.
What is the correct syntax for that group id?

Code:

```py
group_id = 'my_google_group@my_organization.com'
request = service.groups().memberships().searchTransitiveMemberships(parent=f'groups/{group_id}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get get the `group_id` of a group that you know the e-mail of using the gcloud console:

`$ gcloud identity groups describe your-group-name@domain.com`

which will return something similar to:

```
createTime: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z'
displayName: YourGroupName
groupKey:
  id: your-group-name@domain.com
labels:
  cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum: ''
name: groups/8673hkdnjaod98f
parent: customers/Cjas8duwn
updateTime: '2021-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z'
```

the relevant part for you is:

`name: groups/8673hkdnjaod98f`

so in this example the `group_id` is: `8673hkdnjaod98f`

Comment: Thank you Dave! Your solution works perfectly. However, do you a programatically way to get that id? If not I need to parse the output in Python to get the id, which is not a good practice. I tried the lookup() method: https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/groups/lookup but I get the following error: `Cannot bind query parameter. 'groupKey' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types`.

Comment: What's your use-case for needing to programatically look up the `group_id` - they're constant so you could save yourself some trouble by just hard-coding the ID in your app?

Comment: I'm going to hard code them, effectively

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the information from the Cloud Identity’s GCP groups, you have 3 more options or “methods” that are specified in GCP’s official documentation:

1. [Get](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups/get)
2. [List](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups/list)
3. [Directory API: Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups)

In the worst scenario that none of them work, it could be because you don't have an IAM role as "Owner" for GCP, even if you are signing in with your super admin user for G Suite. You can use the following official GCP’s documentation about it here [GCP: Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that the `get()` method needs as parameter the name of the group as this form: `groups/{group_id}`. However, I do not have that group id because it's what I'm looking for in order to use the `searchTransitiveMemberships()` method!

Comment: OK, then the other 2 methods should help you, but I recommend you to confirm that you have the proper IAM role first.

Comment: The other method need access to admin console, which is not possible in big companies. Any other ideas? I saw the lookup() function but can't achieve to make it work because of the following error: `Cannot bind query parameter. 'groupKey' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to comment on Dave's good answer, but I don't have enough rep..

If you do want to get the group name programmatically, in case you're handling several groups for example, have a look at those [docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/memberships-google-groups#adding_a_membership_to_a_google_group).

There, `groupName` gives you the name in the required format (`groups/...`), `group_id` is the email of the group in that case.

Side note: the docs do not seem up to date, I had to remove `+ "&groupKey.namespace=identitysources/" + identity_source_id` from the second line for it to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30873789)